# How to create a full page table with a two columns document

Tags: tables, fullwidth

I'm trying to create a table that occupies both columns in a two columns document. I don't how to fix this problem.

The layout that I want is something like:
[image: what I want]

I tried this:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
% For figures.
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{multirow}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{table*}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
   \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{Metrics} & 
      \multicolumn{4}{c}{C1} &
      \multicolumn{4}{c}{C2} &
      \multicolumn{4}{c}{C3} &
      \multicolumn{4}{c}{C4}\\     
& Mean & SD & Max & Min &  Mean & SD & Max & Min & Mean & SD & Max & Min& Mean & SD & Max & Min \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

[image: what I have]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It seems that you like that all columns have the same width. Try width `XC` columns defined in the  `tabularx` or `tabularray` tables. AAnd, please, please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which we can test as it is.

Comment: you are missing `\begin{document} \end{document}` in your MWE

Comment: @Zarko thanks it worked!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because suggestions in the comments allowed the OP to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your table is quite wide, so you will need to use smaller font size, for example `\footnotesize` that it will fin in text block
- Since table will contain numbers, for them is sensible to use `S` column type defined in `siunitx` package.
- Use `tabullaray` packages with library `siunitx` (which load package of the same name) enable to simple design of table with equal width columns of `S` type:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
    \footnotesize
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {l *{16}{X[c, si={table-format=2.2}]} }, % set table format according to numbers size
             colsep  = 3pt,
             row{1}  = {guard,font=\bfseries},
             row{2}  = {guard}
            }
\SetCell[r=2]{c} Metrics
    &   \SetCell[c=4]{c}   Cluster 1
        &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=4]{c}   Cluster 2
        &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=4]{c}   Cluster 3
        &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=4]{c}   Cluster 4
                    &       &       &   \\
    & Mean  & SD    & Max   & Min
    & Mean  & SD    & Max   & Min
    & Mean  & SD    & Max   & Min
    & Mean  & SD    & Max   & Min       \\
text 1
    & 12.34 &  0.12 & 12.44 & 12.24
    & 12.34 &  0.12 & 12.44 & 12.24
    & 12.34 &  0.12 & 12.44 & 12.24
    & 12.34 &  0.12 & 12.44 & 12.24     \\
text 2
    & 12.34 &  0.12 & 12.44 & 12.24
    & 12.34 &  0.12 & 12.44 & 12.24
    & 12.34 &  0.12 & 12.44 & 12.24
    & 12.34 &  0.12 & 12.44 & 12.24     \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]